# looping through all tables and sorting

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a sub to loop through all tables in my workbook and remove any filters then sort the first column alphabetically
I've come up with the following code but I'm just having some issues with the correct syntax. It will clear the filters but doesn't do the sort.
I've tried to find other solutions on this and other sites but they all seem to refer to particular named ranges which I want to avoid as I'm dealing with multiple tables. I think it's just a problem with how I've done the "key".

```
Private Sub ClearAllFilters()

Dim sht As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lstobj As Excel.ListObject

On Error Resume Next
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each lstobj In sht.ListObjects
        lstobj.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        With lstobj.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=lstobj.DataBodyRange.Columns(1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing the `.Apply` within your `With...End With` block. Also, avoid using `On Error Resume Next` - handle errors if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `Apply` the sorting after you've specified your sort options.

---

Also, a couple recommendations:

- Remove `On Error Resume Next` - handle any errors that may occur (if necessary); this just ignores them and moves on.
- Only a `Worksheet` can have a `ListObject` - a `Chart` sheet can't, for example. So loop through `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`.

---

```
Private Sub ClearAllFilters()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lstobj As ListObject

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each lstobj In sht.ListObjects
        lstobj.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        With lstobj.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=lstobj.DataBodyRange.Columns(1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Apply
        End With
    Next lstobj
Next sht

End Sub
```